When will the 2024 survey results be released?
It's been a month since the 2024 survey closed. When will the results be available? Am I missing something? I don't think so because there's nothing in the Stack Overflow Annual Developer Survey page.
If yes, please share the results link.
For the record, I searched extensively for it.

Last year the survey was in May. Given that the survey was extended until June 20th this year, it may be that this being a vacation period delays the release of the results a bit. I would bet on somewhere in August myself.

it will be released at the most convenient time for marketing

We are currently wrapping up the work necessary for launch and plan to release results very shortly. We look forward to sharing this year's results with you, and thank you so much for your patience.

They have now been released (July 24, 2024):
See https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2024/
